# get value from a SelectBox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

I have a react code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import SelectBox from '../SelectBox';
import Icon from '../Icon';
import Input from '../Input';
import CountryItem from './components/CountryItem';

const PhoneNumber = props => {
  const { children, className } = props;

  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('');
  const [inputParam, setInputParam] = useState('');

  const inputParamChangeHandler = event => {
    const inputChar = event.target.value;
    setInputParam(inputChar);
    console.log({ inputChar });
  };

  const selectedOptionChangeHandler = event => {
    const valueSelected = event.target.value;
    setSelectedOption(valueSelected);
    console.log({ valueSelected });
  };

  console.log({ children });

  const childrenWithPropsFromParent = React.Children.map(children, child => child);

  const optionsWithImage = [
    {
      value: '+880',
      label: <CountryItem />,
    },
    {
      value: '+55',
      label: (
        <span>
          <span className="phone-number__country-flag">
            <Icon name="home" />
          </span>
          <span>
            <span className="phone-number__country-name">Brazil</span>
            <span className="phone-number__country-code">(+55)</span>
          </span>
        </span>
      ),
    },
    {
      value: '+40',
      label: (
        <span>
          <span className="phone-number__country-flag">
            <Icon name="home" />
          </span>
          <span>
            <span className="phone-number__country-name">Romania</span>
            <span className="phone-number__country-code">(+40)</span>
          </span>
        </span>
      ),
    },
    {
      value: '+44',
      label: (
        <span>
          <span className="phone-number__country-flag">
            <Icon name="home" />
          </span>
          <span>
            <span className="phone-number__country-name">United Kingdom</span>
            <span className="phone-number__country-code">(+44)</span>
          </span>
        </span>
      ),
    },
    {
      value: '+1',
      label: (
        <span>
          <span className="phone-number__country-flag">
            <Icon name="home" />
          </span>
          <span>
            <span className="phone-number__country-name">Bahamas</span>
            <span className="phone-number__country-code">(+1)</span>
          </span>
        </span>
      ),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className={classNames('phone-number', className)}>
      <div>Phone Number</div>
      <div className="phone-number__wrapper">
        <SelectBox
          size="small"
          value={selectedOption}
          touched={false}
          onChange={selectedOptionChangeHandler}
          isSearchable={false}
          isDisabled={false}
          isClearable={false}
          options={optionsWithImage}
          width="small"
        />
        <Input value={inputParam} onChange={inputParamChangeHandler} placeholder="XXXX XXX XXX" />
      </div>
      {/* {childrenWithPropsFromParent} */}
    </div>
  );
};

PhoneNumber.defaultProps = {
  children: null,
  className: null,
};

PhoneNumber.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  className: PropTypes.string,
};

export default PhoneNumber;
```

SelectBox Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Select from 'react-select';
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';
import './select-box.styles.scss';
import colorOptions from '../../helpers/colorOptions';
import Tooltip from '../Tooltip';
import Icon from '../Icon';

const sizeBasedSelector = (element, size) => {
  switch (size) {
    case 'tiny':
      return `select-box__${element}--tiny`;
    case 'small':
      return `select-box__${element}--small`;
    case 'large':
      return `select-box__${element}--large`;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

class SelectBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: props.value,
    };
  }

  customTheme = theme => {
    const { primary, primary75, primary50, primary25 } = this.props.colors;

    return {
      ...theme,
      colors: {
        ...theme.colors,
        primary,
        primary75,
        primary50,
        primary25,
      },
    };
  };

  renderPlaceHolder = () => {
    const { preIcon, placeholderText, size } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="select-box__placeholder">
        {preIcon && (
          <span className={classnames('select-box__pre-icon', sizeBasedSelector('pre-icon', size))}>
            {preIcon}
          </span>
        )}
        <span
          className={classnames(
            'select-box__placeholder-text',
            sizeBasedSelector('placeholder-text', size)
          )}
        >
          {placeholderText}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  };

  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    this.props.onChange(selectedOption);
  };

  handleInputChange = inputValue => {
    this.props.onInputChange(inputValue);
  };

  getFlags = () => {
    const { isClearable, isDisabled, isMulti, isSearchable } = this.props;
    return {
      isClearable,
      isDisabled,
      isMulti,
      isSearchable,
    };
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    const {
      autoFocus,
      className,
      classNamePrefix,
      colors,
      errorMsg,
      label,
      name,
      options,
      size,
      touched,
      isMulti,
      isDisabled,
      isCreatable,
      width,
      required,
    } = this.props;
    const hasError = touched && errorMsg;
    const selectProps = {
      ...this.getFlags(),
      autoFocus,
      className: classnames(
        `${className} ${className}--${size}`,
        sizeBasedSelector('width', width),
        {
          'select-box-container--notMulti': !isMulti,
          'select-box-container--error': hasError,
        }
      ),
      classNamePrefix,
      colors,
      theme: this.customTheme,
      value: selectedOption,
      name,
      options,
      onInputChange: this.handleInputChange,
      onChange: this.handleChange,
      placeholder: this.renderPlaceHolder(),
      required,
    };

    return (
      <>
        {label && (
          <span
            className={classnames(`select-box__label select-box__label--${size}`, {
              'select-box__label--required': required,
              'select-box__label--disabled': isDisabled,
            })}
          >
            {label}
          </span>
        )}
        <div className="select-box-wrapper">
          {isCreatable ? <CreatableSelect {...selectProps} /> : <Select {...selectProps} />}
          {errorMsg && (
            <Tooltip
              classNameForWrapper="select-box__tooltip-wrapper"
              classNameForTooltip="select-box__tooltip"
              content={errorMsg}
              position="bottom-right"
              gap={0}
            >
              <Icon name="invalid" />
            </Tooltip>
          )}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

SelectBox.defaultProps = {
  autoFocus: false,
  className: 'select-box-container',
  classNamePrefix: 'select-box',
  colors: {
    primary: colorOptions.coolGray20,
    primary75: colorOptions.coolGray45,
    primary50: colorOptions.coolGray70,
    primary25: colorOptions.coolGray95,
  },
  errorMsg: '',
  isClearable: true,
  isCreatable: false,
  isDisabled: false,
  isMulti: false,
  isSearchable: true,
  label: '',
  name: 'select-box',
  onChange: () => {},
  onInputChange: () => {},
  options: [],
  placeholderText: 'Select...',
  preIcon: null,
  required: false,
  size: 'small',
  touched: false,
  value: null,
  width: 'small',
};

SelectBox.propTypes = {
  autoFocus: PropTypes.bool,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  classNamePrefix: PropTypes.string,
  colors: PropTypes.shape({
    primary: PropTypes.string,
    primary75: PropTypes.string,
    primary50: PropTypes.string,
    primary25: PropTypes.string,
  }),
  errorMsg: PropTypes.string,
  isClearable: PropTypes.bool,
  isCreatable: PropTypes.bool,
  isDisabled: PropTypes.bool,
  isMulti: PropTypes.bool,
  isSearchable: PropTypes.bool,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  onInputChange: PropTypes.func,
  options: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      label: PropTypes.string,
      value: PropTypes.string,
    })
  ),
  preIcon: PropTypes.node,
  placeholderText: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.node]),
  value: PropTypes.oneOf([
    PropTypes.shape({
      label: PropTypes.string,
      value: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
    }),
    PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        label: PropTypes.string,
        value: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
      })
    ),
  ]),
  required: PropTypes.bool,
  size: PropTypes.oneOf(['tiny', 'small', 'large']),
  touched: PropTypes.bool,
  width: PropTypes.oneOf(['tiny', 'small', 'large', 'full']),
};

export default SelectBox;
```

now I want to take the value of the `selectedOption` from the `SelectBox` component but this current code base giving me error while I select a option from the `SelectBox`. The error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at Object.selectedOptionChangeHandler [as onChange] (PhoneNumber.jsx:22)
    at Object.onChange (SelectBox.jsx:71)
    at StateManager.callProp (stateManager-04f734a2.browser.esm.js:98)
    at StateManager._this.onChange (stateManager-04f734a2.browser.esm.js:38)
    at Select._this.onChange (Select-9fdb8cd0.browser.esm.js:1079)
    at Select._this.setValue (Select-9fdb8cd0.browser.esm.js:1106)
    at Select._this.selectOption (Select-9fdb8cd0.browser.esm.js:1155)
    at onSelect (Select-9fdb8cd0.browser.esm.js:1732)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:336)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:385)
```

How to get the value from onChange from the `SelectBox` using the current implementation?

Comment: Do some basic debugging: insert `console.log(event)` at the start of the function. What the error means is that when accessing `event.target.value`, `event.target` is `undefined`, it's as simple as that. Which means that `event` doesn't have a `.target` property.

Comment: Can you include your `SelectBox` component code to see how `onChange` is implemented?

Comment: @DrewReese added the `SelectBox` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SelectBox` component's `handleChange` callback outputs the selected value versus an event, so you should consume the value.

SelectBox

```
handleChange = selectedOption => {
  this.setState({ selectedOption });
  this.props.onChange(selectedOption); // <-- sends selected value!
};
```

PhoneNumber

```
const selectedOptionChangeHandler = valueSelected => { // <-- consume valueSelected
  setSelectedOption(valueSelected);
  console.log({ valueSelected });
};
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a reference question for the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined` type error? Because this is definitely a duplicate of that. I see these types of question every day, and my suspicion is that people don't understand what the error means in the first place, otherwise solving the issue on their own would be trivial.

Comment: @ChrisG Right, totally agree, but no, I don't know if there exists a bank of FAQ's, but I suspect it is because although a similar issue the use-cases are potentially different. SO covers so many languages and aspects of programming that most of the help meta is so generalized. About the best I've come up with is bookmarking good answers I find for frequently seen questions/issues. This one I wanted to see what the `onChange` handler was returning because potentially it could have been an issue with the event object. I've found that debugging is a very acquired skill.